# codeigniter jquery dependent dropdown

Tags: jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I made this dependent dropdown, for the first dropdown, it's already been loaded from the the mysql database, but for the second dropdown, it couldn't be loaded by the first value.

VIEW

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="form-email">Country</label>
    <select name="country" id="country" class="form-control" onChange="get_state(this.value, 'ship');">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Pilih Voucher</option>
        <?php
        if ($results) {
        foreach ($results as $row) {
        echo "<option value=\"" . $row -> country_id . "\">" . $row -> country_name . "</option>";
        }
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="form-email">State Option</label>
    <select name="state_ship" id="state_ship" class="form-control">
        <option value="" selected="selected">State Option</option>
        <?php
        if ($result_state) {
            $str = 1;
            foreach ($result_state as $row) {
            while($str <= $row -> country ){
            echo "<option value=\"" . $str . "\">" . $str . "</option>";
            $str++;
            }
        }
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

MY CONTROLLER

```
public function ship()
{
    $data=array(
       'results'=> $this->produk_model->getAllData('produk'),
        );
    $this->load->view('transaksi/header'); 
    $this->load->view('transaksi/ship', $data);   
    $this->load->view('transaksi/footer');  


public function get_state($country)
{

    $this->db->where('country_id', $country_id);
    $result_state = $this->db->get('country_name');   
}
```

MY MODEL

```
public function getAllData($table)
    {
        return $this->db->get($table)->result();
    }
```

JQUERY

```
 function get_state(value, type)
    {
            $('#state_' + type).html('Loading State...');
            $.ajax({
               dataType      : "json",
                type     : "POST",
                url      : "produk/get_state",
                data     : "data=" + value + "&type=" + type,
                success  : function(res){
                        $('#state_' + type).html('');
                        if(res.status == 200)
                        {
                            for(var i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++)
                            {

                                $('#state_' + type).append('<option value="' + res.data[i].id_country + '">' + res.data[i].nama_country + '</option>');
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $('#state_' + type).append('<option> Data Unloaded </option>');
                        }
                    },
                error   : function(){ 
            },
                timeout: 50000          
            });             
        }
    }
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(data)
{
    $('#state_ship').html('<option value="">-- Select State--</option>');

        $.each(data, function(i, data){
        $('#state_ship').append("<option value='"+data.state_id+"'>"+data.state_name+"</option>");
        });
}
```

And On Your View

```
     <div class="form-group">
         <label class="sr-only" for="form-email">State Option</label>
   <select name="state_ship" id="state_ship" class="form-control">
   </select>
    </div>
```